# Active Record to get children based on condition of parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have a db setup:

```
User has_many :cars
Car  has_many :timeslips
Timeslip  has_one :car
```

I need to only return the :timeslips when the parent :car has a certain :user_id

In my controller I want to say something like this:

```
@timeslips = Timeslip.car.where(:user_id => params[:user_id])
```

what could be the best practice/way to return all children when a parent condition is met? Should I be doing a method in the model?

Answer (score 1):

I would use an ActiveRecord join: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

```
@timeslips = Timeslip.joins("INNER JOIN cars on timeslips.car_id = cars.id").where("cars.user_id = ?", params[:user_id])
```